# no method matching size(::DataFrames.GroupedDataFrame)

Tags: dataframe, julia

It's the first time a post a question, so I will try to give some example but I might not be totally aware of the best way to do it.

I am using groupby() function to divide a DataFrame according to a pooled variable. My intent is to create from the SubDataframes a new one in which the rows splitted with groupby() become 2 separate columns. For instance a in DataFrame A I have :meanX and :Treatment, in dataframe B I want to have :meanX_Treatment1 and :meanX_Treatment2.

Now I found a way to use join() for this pourpose, but having many other variables to block I need to repeat the operation several time and I need to know how many SubDataFrames the initial call of groupby() created. The result is variable so I can't simply read it I need to store it in a variable, that's why I tried size(::DataFrames.GroupedDataFrame).

Is there a solution?

Comment: Is `length(grouped_df)` what you are looking for?

Comment: For this kind of use case I'd also recommend looking into the Query.jl framework. http://www.david-anthoff.com/Query.jl/stable/

Comment: Yes it is, thank you! I really look in the wiki of DataFrames and I couldn't find  how to do it.

Comment: @DarioSarra if the answer is fine, "accept" it in Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

To get the number of groups in a GroupedDataFrame use the `length` method. For example:

```
using DataFrames

df = DataFrame(x=repeat(1:4,inner=2,outer=2),y='a':'p')
grouped = groupby(df,:x)

num_of_groups = length(grouped)   # returns 4

# to do something with each group `for g in grouped ... end` is useful
```

As noted in comments, you might also consider using Query.jl (see documentation at http://www.david-anthoff.com/Query.jl/stable) for data processing along the question's lines.

Comment: well, `Query` is not a substitute for `DataFrames` as it seems imply from the answer, but a higher-level .. query API (PS: the link is broken)

Comment: @Antonello Thanks. Fixed-up answer.